# Can I specify Speech text for a Permission context in DialogFlow?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Can I specify Speech text for a Permission context in DialogFlow?

The samples and spec usually show:

```
return conv.ask(new Permission({ context: 'text to read', permissions: 'name of permission' }));
```

However, the 'text' that I want to display has accented characters in it that mess up the TTS engine. In the regular `SimpleResponse`, the text and speech can be separated:

```
 conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
                speech: '<speak>Go right</speak>',
                text: 'Go -->'
            }));
```

Is there any way to specify the Speech for a Permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only content that can go along with a Permission is the plaintext `context` property that you provide in the Permission constructor.

If it isn't working well, you may want to reconsider your design, as the context parameter is not meant to contain a lot of text.